# Redirect child process's stderr to a caller's buffer

Tags: c, windows, redirect, process, stderr

[Windows7] [x64] [C99] [MinGW-GCC] [+GTK] [-DISK FILE I/O]

---

How do I capture the `stderr` from a child process and record it in a string buffer, able to be printed from the caller?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that directly in C. Create a `pipe`, use `dup2` to redirect the child's `stderr` (file 2) to the pipe.  Read from to pipe in the parent process and print or store in memory as needed.

Keep in mind that the child process may block while writing to its stderr file if the pipe is full. The parent process must read from the pipe to keep the child running.

Comment: Well for that purpose I have `g_threads` to use so the main program will not freeze. `pipe` and `dup2` are linux/unix-specific not windows.

Comment: The Windows solution is analogous.  CreatePipe() and the `STARTUPINFO` structure.